# No identifier specified error Symfony2 Doctrine ORM mapping

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When I try to run `php app/config doctrine:schema:update --force` or just symply open my project in the web browser I get this error:

```
MappingException: No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "Registration\BusinessBundle\Entity\BusinessUser". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.
```

Manually deleted the app/cache folder but the problem remained. If I try to delete cache via command `php app/console cache:clear` I get the same error.

BusinessUser Entity:

```
<?php
namespace Registration\BusinessBundle\Entity;

//use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="business_user")
 */
class BusinessUser
{
    /*
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /*
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $surname;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    /**
     * Set surname
     *
     * @param string $surname
     * @return BusinessUser
     */
    public function setSurname($surname)
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get surname
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSurname()
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to change the strategy of the id column from AUTO to IDENTITY.

Comment: That didn't make any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Entity does not contain PHP docblock comments where your Doctrine Annotation is used.

Docblocks are startet with two asterisks, otherwise it's just a simple comment.

Change your current code

```
/*
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer") 
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") 
 */
protected $id;
```

to

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer") 
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") 
 */
protected $id;
```

Only with /** will annotations be recognized by Doctrine.

Check your other properties too.